# Define ProxyPass (Apache) to serve same page in all paths

Tags: apache, location, virtualhost, proxypass

How can I use ProxyPass to serve always the index.html, from all URLs that begins with /page ?
I need the browser keep the address typed.

Example:
site.com/page/home/2
In browser keep site.com/page/home/2 on address bar, but the apache serve site.com/index.html (to all paths that begin with /page

I have tried:

```
        ProxyRequests     Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On

        <Location /page/* >
            ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1/index.html
            ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1/index.html
        </Location>
```

Comment: And?  What is the result, what is your question?  I just tried your config on my Apache, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

That is not at all what the proxy feature as offered by the http server is for.

Instead you should implement a simple internal rewriting:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?page/ /index.html [QSD,END]
```

It is best to implement such a rule in the http server's (virtual) host configuration. If you do not have access to that you can instead use a *distributed* configuration file (typically called ".htaccess"), that feature needs to be enabled and the file has to be located in the http hosts `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder. The rule will work likewise.

Two major advantages over using the proxy feature:

1. You do *not* need a dull second, internal http request for each and every incoming request, so the performance is much better, the load on the server reduced.
2. The rewriting module is a standard feature in nearly every installation of an apache http server. The proxy module is *not* .